# Programmatically change SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp

Hi we have a CRM System that needs to change SMTP server once updated by the admin.
We have a table that returns a set of data that contains the SMTP Settings that has a status of 1 needed. The problem is it still relays to the localhost smtp even i've sent the SMTP settings to the htmlMimeMail.php (class) Here is my code:

```
function sendEmail($txtFrom, $subject, $to, $cc = NULL, $bcc = NULL, $strHTML, $txtModel='')
    {
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM smtp_server WHERE status='1'";
        $rstemp = $this->cn2->Execute($sql);
        while(!$rstemp->EOF)
        {
            $SMTPid = $rstemp->fields['id'];
            $SMTPServer = $rstemp->fields['server'];
            $SMTPPort = $rstemp->fields['port'];
            $SMTPusername=$rstemp->fields['user'];
            $SMTPpass=$rstemp->fields['pass'];
            $SMTPauth = $rstemp->fields['auth'];
            $rstemp->MoveNext();
        }
        $rstemp->Close();


        $fromEmail  = $txtFrom;
        $from       = $fromEmail;

        $mail = new htmlMimeMail();
        $mail->setTextCharset('utf-8');
        $mail->setHtmlCharset('utf-8');
        $mail->setHeadCharset('utf-8');
        $mail->setSMTPParams($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort,$SMTPid,base64_encode($SMTPusername),base64_encode($SMTPpass),$SMTPServer);         
        $mail->setReturnPath($fromEmail);
        $mail->setFrom($from);
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        $mail->setHTML($strHTML);

        if(trim($txtModel) != '')
        {
            $file   = strtoupper($txtModel).".pdf";

            if(file_exists($this->dir.$file))
            {
                $attachment = $mail->getFile($this->dir.$file);
                $mail->addAttachment($attachment, $file, "application/pdf");
            }
        }

        if (!is_null($cc) && $cc != '') 
        {
            //$arrEmail = explode(",", $cc);
            $mail->setCc($cc);
            //unset($arrEmail);
        }

        $mail->setBcc($bcc.', sample@email.com');

        $arrEmail = explode(",", $to);      
        ini_set("SMTP",$SMTPServer);
        $result = $mail->send($arrEmail);

        return $result;
    }
```

Am i missing something in my code?
I also added ini_set

Here is the function that receives the parameters.

```
function setSMTPParams($host = null, $port = null, $auth = null, $user = null, $pass = null,$helo = null)
{
    if (!is_null($host)) $this->smtp_params['host'] = $host;
    if (!is_null($port)) $this->smtp_params['port'] = $port;
    if (!is_null($helo)) $this->smtp_params['helo'] = $helo;
    if($auth == 4){
        if (!is_null($auth)) $this->smtp_params['auth'] = true;
    }else{
        if (!is_null($auth)) $this->smtp_params['auth'] = false;
    }
    if (!is_null($user)) $this->smtp_params['user'] = $user;
    if (!is_null($pass)) $this->smtp_params['pass'] = $pass;
}
```

```
Table definition
________________________________________
id|server           |port|user|pass|auth |status
________________________________________
1 |localhost        |25  |null|null|false|0
4 |somesmtp@mail.com|25  |user|pass|true |1
________________________________________
```

Comment: tried, just to test, hard coding the values rather than pulling them from the db?

Comment: tried also hard coded values still relays on the localhost i think im lacking something but i dont know what it is.. any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you sent the SMTP data to the class, but you neglected to tell the class to use that data:

```
$result = $mail->send( $a_to, 'smtp' )
```

Failing to set the second parameter in send results in the class defaulting to 'mail' as send type.

```
function send($recipients, $type = 'mail')
```

which then results in your system using the default PHP:

```
$result = mail($to, $subject, $this->output, implode(CRLF, $headers));
```

in the:

```
case 'mail':
```

of function send()

I'm not clear on why the setup resorted to the SMTP defaults that are set when htmlMimeMail class is launched, there may be some further modification of the code that creates that result, I can't say.

I realize this question is a bit old and the current htmlMimeMail won't run without errors on current PHP anyway, but figured might as well give an answer.